# flash as3 embeding simplified chinese - massive file size

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, embed, cjk

So I am trying to embed some simplified Chinese into my flash file. When I turn off embed fonts the flash file is fine. If I add simplified chinese char set it makes the swf massive.

Is there a way to embed a smaller character set than the ones flash offers.

Standad English Characters if I add all the characters and pnctuation amount to 106, simplified Chinese is 11,218 it just is not doable.

So

(i) Can I smooth html text in flash

or

(ii) Can I used a reduced character set?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which characters you want to embed with the textfield in the embed properties panel.

If you don't want to type every char you want to embed, you can embed the with Flex, using unicodeRange property to specify which chars you want to embed, then import the resulting swf into Flash.

Good luck.